# AngularJS Transcluded directive's scope catch from other Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I got transcluded directive, for example '**aDirective**' and other random '**bDirective**' directive. My task is: I want to get a '**aDirective's** scope variable and catch it in '**bDirective**'.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('bDirective',['$scope',function(scope){

    scope.getScopeVar = function () {

    // here I want to get aDirective - s 'someVar' variable
    scope.someVar;

        debugger;
    };
    scope.getScopeVar();
  }])
  .directive('aDirective',function(){
    return{
    scope:{},
    transclude:true,
    template:'<div>123</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude){
      scope.someVar = 'asd';

      transclude(scope, function (clone) {
        element.append(clone);
      });
    }
    };
});
```

Any solutions? 
Regards Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested directive should [`require` the directive from the top](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate). Then it can receive its controller as a `link` function argument (the 4th one).

```
.directive('nestedDirective', function(){
 return {
   require: '^aDirective',
   link: function (scope, elements, attrs, aDirectiveController) {
     // access aDirectiveController's methods or properties
   }
 }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way of making this without **require: '^aDirective',**? Because, that **transclude: true** Directive is global directive and I can not require only one particular Directive from it.

Comment: You `require` directive in the directive that is nested (transcluded), not the one that declares transclusion with `transclude: true`.